# How to append data for each div separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simple but I dont know how to do it. I am trying to append data for each div separately $. Each function is looping and assigning whole data to the same div.
These are my two div.

```
     <div class="div1">
                    <div class="div2">
         // whole javascript code is here
                </div>
         </div>
```

The whole code is something like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $.getJSON("/Post/GetPosts", null, function(data)
              {
               htmlResultData="<br /> " + "Users received from server: " + "<br />";
               $.each(data, function (i, item)
               {
              htmlResultData += item.PostedByName + "<img src='" + item.PostedByAvatar + "'height='100' width='100'/> ";
               });
                $(".div2").empty().append(htmlResultData);
            //however, i have tried to return false here but still same result
               return false;
             });
           });
```

Div1 contains outer CSS for that particular div2. I want to generate multiple div2 for each data returned from the server. I have tried using return false but still same result. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: what is your json response? Please can you give sample?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi there is nothing to do with json. data is returned in correct format but all the five records are showing in same div. i want to append each record to each seperate div not to the same div. hope u understands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you. I have change the code to make it simple.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Post/GetPosts", null, function (data) {

       //make parent div blank
        $(".div1").html("");

        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        //make html for div2
        var html += "<div class='div2'>";
            html += item.PostedByName;
            html += "<img src='" + item.PostedByAvatar + "'height='100' width='100'/>"
            html += "</div>";

            //append all div2 to parent div1
            $(".div1").append(html);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Welcome @duke.

Answer (score 0):

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $.getJSON("/Post/GetPosts", null, function(data)
          {
           htmlResultData="<br /> " + "Users received from server: " + "<br />";
           $.each(data, function (i, item)
           {
          htmlResultData +="<div class='div2'> item.PostedByName + "<img src='" + item.PostedByAvatar + "'height='100' width='100'/></div> ";
           });
            $(".div1").empty().append(htmlResultData);
        //however, i have tried to return false here but still same result
           //return false;
         });
       });
```